# Next Js Build very slow in AWS's EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, build, next.js13

I'm trying to build my Next js App in a EC2 running Amazon Linux with a t2.micro. So far I've been able to pull the github repo, install dependencies and everything inside it. But when it comes to building the app it just never finish the build process.

Has anyone experienced something like this before?

- I've tried a few times but it builds for hours and if I cancel the build, it just crashes the instance, and I can't reconnect if I don't reboot the instance.
- I have tried building the app locally and everything works well, I also checked to have the same node version just in case and installed all dependencies.
- I have also modified the instance credit specification to *unlimited*

Comment: Solved it updating from the t2.micro to a t2.small

Answer (score 0):

faced the same issue three months ago.

Do not try to build it on the server as it will crash the server every time. Build the project on a local machine, push it to the Github repository, and then take pull on the server.

Comment: "Build the project on a local machine, push it to the Github repository"—tracking build artifacts in Git is an antipattern. It's almost always the wrong solution.

Comment: My answer was to clarify that, you shouldn't build your Next Js project on a server.
And you can use any other method for moving build to the server. 
E.g. FTP client like Filezilla.
thanks for pointing it out though